# Proget Server Up but Feed Inaccessible in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, proget

We have reinstalled ProGet as we rebuilt our server after a security hole was discovered (unrelated to ProGet). The feed is visible in the browser, but inaccessible in Visual Studio.

While rebuilding our server, we have ProGet running on a temporary Azure server, which is working and serving our NuGet packages. In comparing the two, one notable difference is the API endpoint URL for the feed. For the ProGet on Azure, it is a reasonable looking, fully qualified URL. 
[image]
On the ProGet we're attempting to set up while building our new server, it actually contains a password and the word "Default" (we have deprecated this password). 
[image]
This doesn't seem to be right, but I don't think it can be changed. I've tried reinstalling ProGet, but it's retaining my packages and the feed.

How can I fix this so ProGet will serve Visual Studio? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was corrected by clearing the value in the ODataBaseUrl in Advanced Settings. Upon doing this, the API Endpoint URL changed to what it should be- a fully qualified URL rather than a strange string.

Answer (score 1):

What version of ProGet are you using?

If it's v3.7 or later, the "Package Source URL" on the Feed Overview page is what you want to enter into Visual Studio:

[image: ProGet Feed Overview Page]

The "Default" you're seeing is simply the feed name, and there are no passwords visible in that URL. The host name displayed there is simply the name of the machine it's running on, so you can also use a DNS name or IP address if you're on Azure (i.e. http://{sitename}.cloudapp.net/nuget/{feedname})

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that I'm using the correct package source url. Note the new pictures added in the question. The Azure is 3.6.x and the one we're trying is 3.7.x